# FakeItEasy: how to unit test abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class, fakeiteasy

I want to mock abstract class public method to returns different values. Is it doable using fakeiteasy?

```
public class Worker: IInterface
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
      provate readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

      public Worker(ILogger logger, IServiceProvider provider) 
      {
          _logger = logger;
          _serviceProvider = provider;
      }

      public Handler(Order order) 
      {
         var service = _serviceProvier.GetService(order.Properties.Type);
         service.DoTaskAsync(...);
      }
}

public abstract class ServiceBases 
{
    public async Task DoTaskAsync(...);
}


[Fact]
public async Task WorkerHandler_Return_Success()
{
    // how to mock  ServiceBases.DoTaskAsync to returns null or throw exception ?

}
```

Comment: If you're trying to test `Worker`, you *don't* mock it. You mock the *dependencies* that `Worker` uses.

Comment: In this case, I think you should fake both `IServiceProvider` as well as `ServiceBases` - in the first you need to fake the `GetService` method to return your fake  of `ServiceBases`.

Comment: The issue is ServiceBases is abstract class and it is not interface. So I cannot use A.CallTo() to fake the return value for fservice.DoTaskAsync() results.

Comment: @susanna you can mock an abstract class and use `A.CallTo` to configure its methods. However the methods need to be virtual.

Comment: Check documentation page [What can be faked](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/)

Comment: thanks for your comments, and make me have more knowledge about using fakeiteasy for abstract class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is complicated because you've got two things to figure out:

1. How to create a mock of your abstract class
2. How to set up your `IServiceProvider` to return an instance of the class that inherits from the abstract class.

Let's start with mocking the abstract class. The easiest way to do that is to create a class that implements the abstract class. You could do this:

```cs
public class FakeServiceBases : ServiceBases
{
    public int NumberOfTimesCalled { get; private set; }
    public override async Task DoTaskAsync()
    {
        NumberOfTimesCalled++;
    }
}
```

Presumable you're mocking this so that you can make sure the class that depends on this calls `DoTaskAsync()`. If you create an instance of this fake class then when `Handler` calls it, it will increment the value. When the test runs you can check that the value has been incremented.

Or maybe you want to make sure that the expected arguments were passed. I don't know what the arguments are, but when `DoTaskAsync()` is called you can add the arguments to a list instead of incrementing a number, like this:

```cs
public class FakeServiceBases : ServiceBases
{
    public List<SomeArgumentType> CallsToDoAsync { get; } = new List<SomeArgumentType>();
    public override async Task DoTaskAsync(SomeArgumentType someArgument)
    {
       CallsToDoAsync.Add(someArgument);
    }
}
```

Same thing. After calling your `Handler` method you can inspect the arguments that were passed to `service.DoTaskAsync` by looking at what's in the `CallsToDoAsync` list.

That takes care of mocking `ServiceBases`. The other step is getting your `IServiceProvider` to always return a `FakeServiceBase` regardless of the type passed to it.

That you can do with FakeItEasy.

```cs
var fakeServiceBase = new FakeServiceBases();
var serviceProvider = A.Fake<IServiceProvider>();
A.CallTo(() => serviceProvider.GetService(A<Type>.Ignored)).Returns(fakeServiceBase);

var testSubject = new Worker(NullLogger.Instance, serviceProvider);
```

This creates a faked `IServiceProvider`. Whenever `GetService` is called, regardless of the type passed to it, it will return the instance of `FakeServiceBases` that you created. After calling methods on the `Worker` you can inspect `fakeServiceBase` to make sure methods were called on it like you expected.

---

We can make this class easier to test by removing the dependency on `IServiceProvider`.

Let's change `Worker` to look like this:

```cs
public class Worker 
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly Func<Type, ServiceBases> _getServicesBases;

    public Worker(ILogger logger, Func<Type, ServiceBases> getServicesBases)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _getServicesBases = getServicesBases;
    }

    public async Task Handler(Order order)
    {
        // Calls the function - passes a Type and gets a ServiceBases
        var service = _getServicesBases(order.Properties.Type);
        service.DoTaskAsync(...);
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't depend on `IServiceProvider`. It depends on a `Func<Type, ServiceBases>`. In other words, it depends on a function that will take a `Type` and return an object that implements `ServicesBases`.

When you're registering your types in your `Startup` you can do this:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<Func<Type, ServiceBases>>(serviceProvider =>
    new Func<Type, ServiceBases>(type => (ServiceBases)serviceProvider.GetService(type)));
```

So at runtime the function will actually resolve the type from the `IServiceProvider`.

But now that your class depends on a function, the mock is even simpler. You don't need to mock an `IServiceProvider`. Instead, you provide a "real" function that returns your `FakeServiceBases`:

```cs
var fakeServiceBase = new FakeServiceBases();
Func<Type, ServiceBases> getServiceBases = type => fakeServiceBase;

var testSubject = new Worker(NullLogger.Instance, getServiceBases);
```